# How to get more than 1000 records using Azure resource graph API

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rest-api, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to get records out using logic app. However due to the graph limit I can only get 1000 records out. What is the best way to get all the records out? . Please see the logic app below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Pagination, try it out and see how many per page you need

[image]

Comment: that gives me "The response is not a valid paginated response. The paginated response is missing a property 'value' of type array." error

Comment: I haven't tried to do this in Logic App, but based on that error, you probably need to set options.resultFormat = objectArray.  See REST API specs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureresourcegraph/resourcegraph(2020-04-01-preview)/resources/resources?tabs=HTTP#queryrequestoptions